# how to sync account (gmail) from terminal

Tags: android, adb, appium

Is there any adb or appium command , which will enable Accounts and Sync?
For example I have added multiple gmail accounts in my android device now i need to enable sync now.

Comment: you may have to use uiautomator to automate the ui process and call via `addb shell `

Comment: But i don't think there is any adb command for sync option

Comment: yes, I am not aware of direct adb command for sync,But using uiautomator you call as single adb command.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Sync now all account

```
adb shell requestsync
```

Sync account by name

```
adb shell requestsync -n <account-name>
```